# Cleaning the special characters and converting float into int for multiple columns in Python, Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I am cleaning a large dataset which has 300 columns. Most of the columns have special characters and float. How to remove the special characters and convert the float into int? I have close to 20 columns. Please suggest.

Sample columns

Column 1

```
5.179411048

6.979664266

6.801623755

6.357895491

5.672671138

5.986308293

6.916835392

6.113538245

7.854630746

6.264289168

6.183119587

5.838588332

6.840507371

8.333833257

6.188446205

8.309021165




7.34162041

5.230597972

5.247489061

8.181107798

5.536886048

6.313108318

8.128615238
```

Column 2

```
5.959064936999185\H

5.559656080630483\G

4.984461828692988\B

5.160616481113521\Z

6.2\C$$@@@

5.462299069965385\P

5.23564876@4126072\G

5.275847049000189\J


5.13407947424$9958\G

5.204035084141148\R

5.625365837737466\W

5.551530319919428\T

5.143210079430139\Q
```

Comment: 300 colummns or 20 columns?

Comment: Use `regex` to get number out of it and convert it into int. you should provide expected output too.

Comment: Please do not confuse StackOverflow for being a free code writing service. Take the [tour], read [ask] and maybe https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ What did you try yourself?

Comment: @Yunnosch Datasets have 300 coulmns. I need to clean 20 columns which has characters and float